# Android slow cold start with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, cold-start

I felt my application cold start is slow and was more sure when Firebase Performance mentioned that.

I used logcat `Displayed` to make an initial compare which displayed at my Samsung galaxy S8:

```
/.list.MainActivity: +2s81ms
```

This is replicated by pressing the `play` button at Android Studio `>>` closing the app from my cellphone `>>` opening it again in my phone (i.e. not with android studio)

Comparing to known applications the fast applications at about 400ms and the slower (such as Whatsapp and facebook) are 1s, so 2 seconds is a lot!

I spent almost 2 days and ended up finding the following,

If i am making a simple **Hello World** application, the **cold start time is about 0.660s**, which is a lot for an application doing nothing and compared to released applications with as little as 0.350s

And if i am adding the next 4 lines in gradle (without any extra code!)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.0'
```

The **cold start increased to about 1.2s** which is even more than Whatsapp and Facebook

How is it that the cold start for such a simple code is so slow? Am i missing any settings in Android studio? Perhaps the manifest or gradle? What can i do to improve that?

[Hello world with firebase gradle implementation](https://github.com/ranco980/test-performance)

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking.  "What am I missing" doesn't seem actionable.

Comment: I modified the last sentence to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns our there is a very big different between debug and release versions. After i created a release version for alpha testers on google play with the `minifyEnabled`, `shrinkResources`, `debuggable` set to `false` etc. the app cold start is now about 700ms.

Also, i am not sure, if there is a difference between an app just installed and one installed and cold started after several times (not to be confused by warm start of course)

That does not completely explain all the things i experienced and i am still a bit confused about, but i am guessing there is much about the android system (and firebase) unknown to me which can affect the cold start time

Answer (score 0):

When you add Firebase to your app, it merges in a ContentProvider that [automatically loads and initializes](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html) Firebase so that the APIs are ready for use as soon as your code is invoked.  You're paying the cost of that.  But that doesn't necessarily explain everything, since we can't see exactly what else your app might be doing, or how your measure the startup time.

Comment: As mentioned, i am searching the "Displayed" keyword in Logcat under "No Filters" to compare the cold start times between the app and other apps on my cellphone and  the code is at the link bellow. There is nothing in it besides the firebase implementations. 1.2s is a lot for such an empty app, i am not sure it make sense.